# GoLang Table Test

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a standard table-test unit-test in Go. How can I make it simpler, easy to read and succinct?

**I'm looking suggestions for: Structural refactoring. Less and simple code to achieve the same thing.**

**test.go**

```
func Test_Parses_Books(t *testing.T) {
    books := xmlDoc.Book

    type tester struct {
            texts           []Text
            bookID          int
            categoryLen     int
    }

    getBookTest := func(i int) tester {
            book := books[i]
            return tester{
                    texts:           book.BookNames,
                    bookID:          book.BookID,
                    categoryLen:     len(book.Categories),
            }
    }

    booklen := len(books)
    if booklen != 4 {
            t.Errorf("expected: 4. got: %d", booklen)
    }

    var testTable = []struct {
            expected tester
            actual   tester
    }{{
            expected: tester{
                    texts: []Text{
                            {"BOOK", "TV"},
                            {"en", "TV"}},
                    bookID:          1,
                    categoryLen:     2},
            actual: getBookTest(0),
    }, {
            expected: tester{
                    texts: []Text{
                            {"BOOK", "PS4"},
                            {"en", "PS4"}},
                    bookID:          5,
                    categoryLen:     2},
            actual: getBookTest(1),
    }, {
            expected: tester{
                    texts: []Text{
                            {"BOOK", "XBOX"},
                            {"en", "XBOX"}},
                    bookID:          22,
                    categoryLen:     1},
            actual: getBookTest(2),
    }, {
            expected: tester{
                    texts: []Text{
                            {"BOOK", "PS3"},
                            {"en", "PS3"}},
                    bookID:          17,
                    categoryLen:     1},
            actual: getBookTest(3),
    }}

    for i, test := range testTable {
            if !reflect.DeepEqual(test.expected, test.actual) {
                    t.Errorf("\nexpected: [%d]\n\t%#v.\ngot:\n\t%#v",
                            i, test.expected, test.actual)
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use the following refactoring for the: Ease-of-read, extensibility and brevity.

Because, I believe, defining new types and function__**s**__ (single, short one seems ok_) inside tests make readability and one-look understandability harder. Tests are meant for documentation as well. They should be clear instantly.

**refactored_test.go**

```
// asserts use testify for brevity
func Test_Parse_Books(t *testing.T) {
  assert := assert.New(t)

  texts := func(text string) []Text {
    return []Text{{"BOOK", text}, {"en", text}}
  }

  exps := []Book{
    {
      Texts:       texts("TV"),
      Categories:  make([]Category, 2),
      ID: 1},
    {
      Texts:       texts("PS4"),
      Categories:  make([]Category, 2),
      ID: 5},
    {
      Texts:       texts("XBOX"),
      Categories:  make([]Category, 1),
      ID: 22},
    {
      Texts:       texts("PS3"),
      Categories:  make([]Category, 1),
      ID: 17}}

  acts := xmlDoc.Books
  assert.Equal(4, len(acts))

  for i, exp := range exps {
    act := acts[i]
    assert.Equal(len(act.Categories), len(exp.Categories))
    assert.Equal(act.ID, exp.ID)
    assert.Equal(act.Texts, exp.Texts)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The actual values should not be part of the table since it is much easier to refer to them as `books[i]` in the loop.

The type `tester` has a bad name since that name sounds active, as if the type could actually *test* something. Choose a more passive name, such as `BookInfo`.

The field `tester.categoryLen` should be named `categoriesLen` since asking for the length of a single category doesn't make sense.

The function `getBookTest` should be named `extractInfo` or something similar.

After renaming and reorganizing the code, it looks like this. But since you did not provide any real test data, I can only hope that it runs fine, I could not actually test it.

```
import (
    "reflect"
    "testing"
)

type Document struct {
    Book []Book
}
type Book struct {
    BookNames  []string
    BookID     int
    Categories []Category
}
type Text string
type Category struct{}

var xmlDoc Document

func Test_Parse_Books(t *testing.T) {
    books := xmlDoc.Book

    type BookInfo struct {
        Texts         []Text
        ID            int
        CategoriesLen int
    }

    extractInfo := func(book Book) BookInfo {
        return BookInfo{
            Texts:         book.BookNames,
            ID:            book.BookID,
            CategoriesLen: len(book.Categories),
        }
    }

    newBookInfo := func(title string, id int, categoriesLen int) BookInfo {
        return BookInfo{
            Texts: []Text{
                {"BOOK", title},
                {"en", title}},
            ID:            id,
            CategoriesLen: categoriesLen}
    }

    booklen := len(books)
    if booklen != 4 {
        t.Errorf("expected: 4. got: %d", booklen)
    }

    var expectedData = []BookInfo{
        newBookInfo("TV", 1, 2),
        newBookInfo("PS4", 5, 2),
        newBookInfo("XBOX", 22, 1),
        newBookInfo("PS3", 17, 1)}

    for i, expected := range expectedData {
        actual := extractInfo(books[i])
        if !reflect.DeepEqual(expected, actual) {
            t.Errorf("wrong value for book %d\nexp: %#v\ngot: %#v",
                i, expected, actual)
        }
    }
}
```